# Solid guage refresh when receives new data (point value)

Tags: vue.js, highcharts

I am having issues with my solid gauge component using the highcharts-vue wrapper.
Basically every time it receives new data it re-draws the animation from 0. Please see sandbox link below for example: https://codesandbox.io/s/n0no0jky1l

The desired behavour im trying to achieve is shown here: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/gauge-solid
Where the gauge animates from old to new value smoothly.
From what i can tell it is not recommended to access the charts methods manually (for example to call the points.update method). (source: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-vue#chart-object-reference)
Any ideas?

Comment: Check out the [example here](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/gauge-solid). Seems you should be using `point.update()` instead of setting new data

Comment: Hi Phil,From what i can tell the highcharts-vue wrapper does not expose these methods for use. ref: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-vue#chart-object-reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It occurs because of mutating data in Highcharts. Please use `Point.update`, instead of updating whole series, to make animation work. You can access whole `Chart` object by reference in your component, specifically `this.children[0].chart`. Here is the code:

```
  watch: {
    title(newValue) {
      this.chartOptions.title.text = newValue;
    },
    points(newValue, oldValue) {
      console.log("watch firing", newValue, oldValue);
      this.$children[0].chart.series[0].data[0].update(oldValue += 1);
    },
    units(newValue) {
      this.chartOptions.series[0].dataLabels.format =
        '<div style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:2rem;color: black">{y}</span><div>' +
        newValue +
        "</div><div/>";
    },
    min(newValue) {
      this.chartOptions.yAxis.min = newValue;
    },
    max(newValue) {
      this.chartOptions.yAxis.max = newValue;
    }
  },
```

Don't worry about your data, Highcharts mutate it, so your `points` prop should be updated every time.

**Live example:** https://codesandbox.io/s/ojkzvo05z

Kind regards!